# Search TYPO3 BE by data present in related model

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

I have an extension with an "event" model with an "address" field related to the "tt_address" model.

In the TCA configuration I have set:

```
ctrl['searchFields'] = 'address'
```

Now, if in TYPO3 BE I search by a name present in the tt_address model, it returns the tt_address record but it doesn't return the "event" record.

Is it possible to configure the TCA so that searching in TYPO3 BE it will returns also the "event" record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not supported. At the time of this writing only the following TCA types are supported in [`searchFields`](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/11.5/en-us/Ctrl/Properties/SearchFields.html):

- text
- flex
- slug
- input

This means searching by relations will not work for the global search in the TYPO3 backend. You will need to implement a custom backend module if you need this.